# Osmnx returns just the start and destination OSM ids when finding route between them

Tags: python, networkx, osmnx

To get the route between two coordinates using osmnx, I used the following code:

```
import osmnx as ox

ox.config(use_cache=True, log_console=True)
G = ox.graph_from_place('Sydney,New South Wales,Australia', network_type='drive')

import networkx as nx
# find the nearest node to the start location
orig_node = ox.get_nearest_node(G,(intersections['lat'][0],intersections['lon'][0]))
# find the nearest node to the end location
dest_node = ox.get_nearest_node(G,(intersections['lat'][1],intersections['lon'][1]))
shortest_route=nx.shortest_path(G,orig_node,dest_node,weight='time')
```

where, intersections is a dataframe that contains the latitude and longitude of various intersections in sydney.

intersections['lat'][0],intersections['lon'][0] represents the latitude and longitude of the 0th entry and so on.
When I plot this, I do get the appropriate results:[Plot showing the route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qp4F.png)

I get the OSM ids of the points in these routes as:
[771347, 1612748582]
But these seem to be the start and destination points itself.
Is there any way I can get all the coordinates in the route shown in the image above using osmnx itself. I'm aware I can use various APIs for this, but since I have 75000 points, and I need to find the routes between all these points(along with the coordinates that form the route), I would like a more efficient solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

`nx.shortest_path()` returns a list of OSM ids of the nodes that form the route.
In **osmnx**, you can get OSM's nodes information using `ox.graph_to_gdfs()` that will return a GeoDataFrame with all the nodes of the graph.
Once you have all the nodes in a GeoDataFrame, you can easily extract the coordinates:

```
# Get the nodes given the graph, as a GeoDataFrame
nodes = ox.graph_to_gdfs(G, nodes=True, edges=False)
# Extract only the nodes that form your route
nodes = nodes.set_index('id').reindex(shortest_route).reset_index()
# Store all the route information into a DataFrame keeping only useful columns
route_df = nodes[['id', 'lon', 'lat']]
```

Answer (score 0):

> But these seem to be the start and destination points itself. Is there any way I can get all the coordinates in the route shown in the image above using osmnx itself.

You *are* getting all the nodes in the route. The origin and destination you provided as an example (OSM IDs [771347](https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/771347) and [1612748582](https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/1612748582)) are adjacent nodes in the graph, because there is no other node between those two off-ramps along this expressway. Hence it is a path comprising only those two nodes.

> I need to find the routes between all these points (along with the coordinates that form the route)

First off, you are using a very old version of OSMnx with several deprecated or obsolete functions in it. Your code can be much more efficient if you refactor it, and even more efficient still if you upgrade to the latest version (v1.2.2 as of this writing) to use its newer functionality. For example, you can find all your nearest nodes at once, using an efficient index, with the [ox.nearest_nodes](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.distance.nearest_nodes) function. And you can solve all your shortest paths in parallel, using multiprocessing, with the [ox.shortest_path](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.distance.shortest_path) function.

```py
import osmnx as ox
ox.settings.use_cache = True
ox.settings.log_console = True

# get graph and add free-flow travel times to its edges
G = ox.graph_from_place("Sydney, New South Wales, Australia", network_type="drive")
G = ox.add_edge_travel_times(ox.add_edge_speeds(G))

# randomly select 1,000 origin/destination points, just for example
n = 1000
points = ox.utils_geo.sample_points(G, n)
orig_points = points[:int(n / 2)]
dest_points = points[int(n / 2):]

# find nearest node to each origin/dest point, then solve paths in parallel
orig_nodes = ox.nearest_nodes(G, X=orig_points.x, Y=orig_points.y)
dest_nodes = ox.nearest_nodes(G, X=dest_points.x, Y=dest_points.y)
paths = ox.shortest_path(G, orig_nodes, dest_nodes, weight="travel_time", cpus=None)

# convert node paths to lat-lng paths
paths_latlng = [[(G.nodes[node]["y"], G.nodes[node]["x"]) for node in path] for path in paths]
```

Note that if you have unsolvable routes in your graph (e.g., due to one-way edges and artificial perimeter effects), you'll need to handle (ignore/skip) those nulls when you convert nodes to lat-lng coordinates.